# Is "maxPwdAge" a constant attribute name for LDAP?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am new to LDAP and I am wondering if attribtue names like "maxPwdAge" and "pwdLastSet" are constant attribute names for LDAP, not just AD?

The reason that I want to know this is because I want to write a program to calculate password expiration time for all systems that use LDAP. If the names are not constant across systems, it might be pretty complicate for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pwdLastReset` is peculiar to Active Directory as far as I know.

`pwdMaxAge` comes from a Internet Draft 'LDAP Password Policy', which is the step before an RFC, which technically expired years ago but which is nevertheless implemented by a number of LDAP servers. In OpenLDAP you have to add the `ppolicy` overlay to get the password-policy attributes to appear.

You should also note that you may not have access to the `pwdLastReset` attribute, and that `pwdMaxAge` is not an attribute of the user at all: it is an attribute of the policy entry, which you may not have access to either.

Answer (score 0):

No. These is no universal standard to determine when a password expires.

As #EJP mentioned, there is a Internet Draft '[LDAP Password Policy](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-behera-ldap-password-policy-10.txt)' that has been implemented to some levels for several LDAP server implementations but it is not universal.

-jim